# How can I delete every n-th row from a dataframe in R, according to grouping variable?

Tags: r

I wish to take every second measurement from a data.frame according to a grouping variable. For example, in the data.frame `Input`, take every second `Sample` for each `ID`:

```
 head(Input, 10)
           Sample    X       ID
    15918      1 -1.326285 EABE_D5
    15919      2 -1.315783 EABE_D5
    15920      3 -1.313245 EABE_D5
    15921      4 -1.304670 EABE_D5
    15922      5 -1.309060 EABE_D5
    15923      1 -1.292412 EABE_D4
    15924      2 -1.294728 EABE_D4
    15925      3 -1.282006 EABE_D4
    15926      4 -1.287245 EABE_D4
    15927      5 -1.278444 EABE_D4
```

and create a new data.frame named `Output`:

```
Output
        Sample   X       ID
15919      2 -1.315783 EABE_D5
15921      4 -1.304670 EABE_D5
15924      2 -1.294728 EABE_D4
15926      4 -1.287245 EABE_D4
```

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you but this results in a data.frame with every `Sample` equal to 2. However, I want every second sample as per my anticipated output.

Comment: what about `Input[Input$Sample %% 2 == 0,]`. This takes only the even numbered samples..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'ID', we `slice` the rows based on the even index returned by `seq`

```
library(dplyr)
Input %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   slice(seq(2, n(), by =2))
#  Sample         X      ID
#   <int>     <dbl>   <chr>
#1      2 -1.294728 EABE_D4
#2      4 -1.287245 EABE_D4
#3      2 -1.315783 EABE_D5
#4      4 -1.304670 EABE_D5
```

---

Or we can use `data.table` for efficiency

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Input)[Input[, .I[seq(2, .N, by = 2)], by = ID]$V1]
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`, we group by 'ID', apply the modulo operator `%%` with y as 2, convert to logical by negating (`!`) and with this logical vector, we subset the rows.

```
Input[with(Input, !ave(Sample, ID, FUN = function(x) x %%2)),]
#      Sample         X      ID
#15919      2 -1.315783 EABE_D5
#15921      4 -1.304670 EABE_D5
#15924      2 -1.294728 EABE_D4
#15926      4 -1.287245 EABE_D4
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be inefficient. However, you can do this in one more way using `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) x[seq(2, nrow(x), by=2),]))


#                Sample   X      ID
#EABE_D4.15924      2 -1.294728 EABE_D4
#EABE_D4.15926      4 -1.287245 EABE_D4
#EABE_D5.15919      2 -1.315783 EABE_D5
#EABE_D5.15921      4 -1.304670 EABE_D5
```

`split`ting the dataframe based on `ID` and then selecting every 2nd row in each group and finally `rbind`ing them using `do.call` to convert the list returned as dataframe.

If you do not want the row names, you can take the dataframe in one variable (say a) and then

```
rownames(a) <- NULL
```